# Pattern for signed number

Tags: android

this is the pattern that I created to accept decimal numbers with 5 integer and 2 decimal numbers.

```
String pattern = "[0-9]{0,5}+([" + ds + "]{1}||[" + ds + "]{1}[0-9]{1,2})?";
```

`ds` is the decimal format symbol.

How can I modify it to accept negative numbers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add `[-+]?` in front, and put what you have between `()`.

If I write the regex, I will write it like this: `[-+]?(\\d{0,5}\\.\\d{1,2}|\\d{1,5}\\.\\d{0,2})`

It will matches these boundary cases:

```
.5
6.
.43
0.
05.50
```

But it will reject `.`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String pattern = "[-+]?[0-9]{0,5}([.]{1}[0-9]{1,2})?"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the negative numbers would start with "-" sign, you just need to put that in the beginning:

```
String pattern = "-?([0-9]{0,5}+([" + ds + "]{1}||[" + ds + "]{1}[0-9]{1,2})?)";
```

Note that I didn't check the validity of the rest of the pattern, just showed how to add the minus sign before everything else.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
String pattern = "^[-+]?\d{1,5}(\.\d{1,2})?$";
```